# If $a^2=a\enspace\forall~a\in R$, then the ring $R$ is commutative

Tags: ring-theory

I think of the following proof:

> Let $a, b\in R$. Then 
>   $(ab)^2=ab$ or, $(ab)(ab)=a^2b^2$ or, $a(ba)b=a(ab)b$ or, $ba=ab$ (by left and right cancellation laws). Hence $R$ is  commutative.

Is this proof correct? Justify.

Comment: Where is your second equality coming from? Because the easiest proof of it that I can think of is to first prove that $R$ is commutative.

It's also not generally the case that rings are cancellative: indeed, if such a ring is cancellative, then cancelling $a$ (on either side) in $a^2 = a$ gives $a = 1$, so your ring is trivial.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2211767, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10274.

Comment: *"Is this proof correct? Justify."* sounds like this proof is not yours but rather from an exercise book. In that case what do you think about this proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect. You don't have cancellations laws in a general ring.

For example, $\overline{2}.\overline{3} = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, yet you can't cancel.